# Broadleaf can i upload same image in Media asset and override images

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

When I upload a media asset in admin side by same name image (like x.png)
this image will create with new name (x-1.png).

I want to replace this image with new image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the original image first, and then upload the new asset with the same name.

Comment: i try to delete image in asset path. but when i upload new image with same name this result will show old image before delete

Comment: Unfortunately, this is due to caching. Restarting the app should knock it back into place. `org.broadleafcommerce.cms.file.dao.StaticAssetDaoImpl#readStaticAssetByFullUrl` sets the Hibernate flag `query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, true);`

Answer (score 0):

you need disable cache first by set:

```
blPU.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
blPU.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
blCMSStorage.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
blCMSStorage.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```

in core/.../default.properties

or override it in admin/ and site/ properties files.