# Broadleaf replace image when upload asset media

Tags: spring-mvc, caching, broadleaf-commerce

Can I replace an image when I upload an asset media file with same name?

ex. in media asset I have cat picture(file name x.png) and I want to upload dog picture (file name = x.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadleaf can i upload same image in Media asset and override images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58537586/broadleaf-can-i-upload-same-image-in-media-asset-and-override-images)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

In the other hand Broadleaf render html via Thymeleaf, so you can checkout it document to override controller and template from framework